# How to make the Microsoft linker show which libraries it is linking with?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

When you compile a program with the Microsoft compiler, then link it, `link.exe` is obviously linking with some libraries by default, the C runtime library at the very least.

How can I get it to print a list of exactly which libraries it is linking with?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what are you looking for, but if you specify the [`/VERBOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages) linker option then the output is quite verbose (about what was searched, loaded, discarded, unused; passes 1 and 2). Also, if you choose to generate a mapfile (see the [`/MAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile) linker option), that file will contain the resultant symbols listings.